# Determining assemblies/DLLs that a .Net executable calls by looking at MSIL?

Tags: .net

This might seem like a bit of an odd question, and I hope I've got my terminology correct...

Is there any way to determine what assemblies or other external .DLLs are called by examining the MSIL of a .Net app?  If so, is it possible to see what function calls are made to those external assemblies or DLLs?

The reason I ask is so:

From the little bit of .Net mobile development I've done so far, it seems that often a programmer must explicitly state the capabilities that the application requires.  For example, suppose a person is writing a .Net app for the Windows Phone platform that requires access to the accelerometer, he/she must explicitly state that the app requires accelerometer use.  It seems like this whole process could potentially be automated by analyzing the include statements of the original source code.  For example, if the line "using Microsoft.Devices.Sensors" is in the source code, that the app most likely requires use of the accelerometer, compass, or light sensor.  The list of requirements for app could then be generated based on the include statements in the source code, rather than having to depend on a programmer specifying things.  So, in the description of the app, it could say "This app requires access this device's sensors."  The problem with doing that is that obviously the source code isn't submitted to the app store.

From the tiny bit of Windows 8 dev I've done, I've noticed that metro-style apps for Windows 8 (or for the Windows Marketplace) are forbidden from calling external DLLs as well as certain other system calls.  This is enforced at compile/build time when the app is being generated.  As an extra security measure, the same sort of technique - examining the MSIL to determine what external assemblies/DLLs are being called could be used as an extra security measure to make sure that no potentially un-sandboxed apps end up on the app store.

Since this isn't already being done, I'm guessing that it's not possible, but I figured it never hurts to ask.  It just seems like such a slick way of determining what an app really needs access to, rather than relying on a potentially sloppy programmer that has decided to require all capabilities for a particular app that doesn't actually use them.

Comment: What about using a tool like Reflector? http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static analysis just isn't sufficient to determine what kind of DLLs or methods the program is going to call.  Unlike languages like Python and VB.NET, the C# language is heavily biased to early-binding and static type checking but it too has plenty of ways to late-bind.  Reflection, the *dynamic* keyword and Activator.CreateInstance() are the principal tools to do so.  And they are also available in a Store or Phone project.

So no, the app still has to be sand-boxed to close that loophole.

Comment: Would it be possible to check for the usage of the dynamic keyword or Activator.CreateInstance() by going through the MSIL?

Comment: Not impossible, just painful since you have to decompile the MSIL.  There just isn't much point to it, what do you do when you see it being used?

Comment: The point of seeing if a particular assembly is used is to mark that .Net program as using a particular feature or as being potentially unsafe.  If you know it contains the dynamic keyword or is able to call Activator.CreateInstance(), then you know the app is potentially unsafe.

Comment: I don't get the point, just run WACK and you get an absolute instead of a maybe.  The label "unsafe" is just no match for "rejected".

Comment: I wasn't aware of WACK.  How exactly does it work - does it examine the MSIL?

Answer (score 2):

For normal DLL's (not .NET DLLs), you can use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) which is a free program made by Microsoft. It will analyze executables and DLL libraries and tell you which other DLLs depend on it.

For .NET DLL's, you can use [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/). You simply load a .NET DLL into reflector, right click on it and go to "Analyze". You will see a "Depends On" item in the window and it will show you all dependencies.

Reflector is no longer free, however. If you don't have it and you are looking for a free solution, use [JetBrains DotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/). It does just about everything Reflector does, including dependency checking.

Finally, if you need an open source solution, you can use [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/). ILSpy also has lists dependencies. And you can peek at the source code to ILSpy to see how its done!

Hope this helps out!

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft provides a tool in the Windows or .Net SDK called [ILDASM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1.aspx) that provides information about an assembly.

Using this tool, you can view the Manifest, which provides all of the dependencies for the assembly.

This tool can also provide output in various formats by using command line switches defined in the linked article.